# Dm a user, if another user pings them

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made an AFK command, and if a user pings someone that is AFK, the bot will send a message in that current channel, that the user he tagged is AFK.

But i want to add something. The bot also needs to privately message the person who is AFK, saying that (user tagged you in this message: user message)

Current code:

````js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 message.mentions.users.forEach((user) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return false;

  if (
   message.content.includes('@here') ||
   message.content.includes('@everyone')
  )
   return false;
  if (db.has(user.id + '.afk'))
   message.channel.send(
    `${message.author}, de persoon die je zojuist hebt getagged is momenteel AFK`
   );
 });
});```
````

Comment: Use `user.send()`

Answer (score 1):

Since you already created the `user` variable after the `message` activity, all you need to do in this case would be to add a line similar to the following:

```
const msgAuthor = message.author.tag
const sentIn = message.channel.id

user.user.send(`${msgAuthor} tagged you in <#${sentIn}>)
```

You must make sure to state `user.send` after the variable you've created, otherwise, it would recognize your variable as a guild channel, causing it to crash.

I hope it was helpful.